Can you cancel a definite integral by deriving
I'm trying to derive the following formula:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\ \left(\int_0^t \left(\frac{1}{x+2}\ \right)^2 dx \right)$$
Can you just cancel out the derivatives as you can with indefinite integrals, as such:
$$\left(\frac{1}{x+2}\ \right)^2$$
Or should you work it through, finding the definite integral and then deriving that:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\ \left(\int_0^t \left(\frac{1}{x+2}\ \right)^2 dx\right)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dt}\ \left(\Bigl[\frac{-1}{x+2}\Bigr]_0^t\right)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dt}\ \Bigl(\frac{-1}{t+2}-\frac{-1}{0+2} \Bigr)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dt}\ \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{t+2}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{t+2}\right)^2$$
Will this always work out to be the same?  Or can it be different depending on the function involved?  From my understanding, you can always cancel out indefinite integrals by deriving with respect to the same variable, but does this logic hold true for definite integrals?
Edit: Fixed dx -> dt
Logically they shouldn't cancel out as they're different variables (dx vs dt) but I've tried 3 different formulas and it keeps getting the same result.  What am I missing?

Your integral is not a function of $x$, so its derivative w.r.t. $x$ is $0$.

That's my bad sorry, the outside should be d/dt.  I'm assuming that then means the first approach is invalid?  If so, why do I seem to keep getting the same answer when I try it with different functions?

I've edited the question to fix this, thanks <3

All you need is FTC. No need to evaluate the integral.

Theorem: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $\phi_1$,$\phi_2$ are differentiable satisfying $\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x)\in (a,b)$, then $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\phi_1(x)}^{\phi_2(x)}f(t)dt=f(\phi_2(x))\phi_2'(x)-f(\phi_1(x))\phi_1'(x)$$

@KingsDev, for any continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ or $f:[a,+\infty)\to\Bbb R,,,$ it results that $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\int_a^t!f(x)\mathrm dx\right)=f(t),.$$Indeed,$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\int_a^t!f(x)\mathrm dx\right)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\big[F(t)-F(a)\big]=F’(t)=f(t)$$ since $,F(t),$ is an antiderivative of the function $f$.
